# Any open source software firewall with country based ip blocking feature?

Tags: linux, firewalls, opensource

I am looking for an open source firewall with country based ip blocking feature for Linux OS.

Comment: Hi sampath, welcome to [security.se]. Please see the [FAQ], and also read [ask] - product recommendation questions are not a good fit for our site (or really any SE site...).

Answer (score 3):

1. `iptables`
2. Access to a geolocation database. As far as I'm aware, these all come with a fee. https://www.google.com/search?q=ip+geolocation
3. A shell script.

Comment: +1 and see this page for a sample script and free source of geo-ip data:  http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/block-entier-country-using-iptables/

Answer (score 1):

[ipinfodb.com](http://ipinfodb.com/ip_country_block_iptables.php) has a free geolocation database that can be used to get IP addresses per country. There's a bash script for using this database with iptables on [this page](http://ipinfodb.com/ip_country_block_iptables.php).